# Getting an empty body every time when sending a linux email with subprocess.call in python

Tags: python, linux

I am writing a python script that will send an email when an exception is raised. I am getting the email, however, the body is empty every time - I get the `Null message body; hope that's ok` message when the subprocess is called.

Here is my code:

```
subject = "This is the subject"
f = open('body.txt', "w+")
body = "Email body goes here."
f.write(body)
subprocess.call(['mail', '-s', subject, 'addr@example.com'],stdin=f)
f.close()
```

Why am I getting an empty body every time? I don't think I am understanding how stdin in `subprocess` exactly works.

Comment: Why exactly are you doing this instead of using the standard library modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close `f` *before* calling `subprocess.call()`.  Otherwise, `f` won't be flushed by the time `mail` reads it, and there will be no guarantee that anything has actually been written to the file.

Comment: This was what I was missing! Thanks!